# How to check if pipeline parameter is empty

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I have a pipeline job which includes Credentials parameter:
[image: Pipeline]

In the pipeline file I have the below code:

```
stage ("create bundle"){
            steps{
                script{
                        amd_distribution_create_bundle credential_id: params.DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID, distribution_url: params.DISTRIBUTION_URL, gps_credential_id: params.GPG_PASSPHRASE, bundle_name: params.BUNDLE_NAME, bundle_version: BUNDLE_VERSION
                }
            }
        }
```

how can I ask before calling the groovy method 'amd_distribution_create_bundle', if some pipeline field is empty?

Comment: ^^ This is the exact answer to check only if a _parameter_ is defined. I usually use expression `env.PARAM_NAME != null` or just `env.PARAM_NAME` to be able to override parameters by _environment variables_. These resolve to `true` if the parameter or an environment variable of the same name exist (not null) or exist and evaluate to `true` in boolean context (e. g. string is non-empty).

Comment: can you write me the correct if statement syntax I should use?

Comment: `if(params.containsKey('GPG_PASSPHRASE'))` or what I prefer `if(env.GPG_PASSPHRASE)`.

Comment: Basically yes. If you still have issues, I suggest to post a new question.